# xslt - Recursive Empty Node Cleanup

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to clean up a file with arbitrary element names that looks like:

```
<root>
    <nodeone>
        <subnode blah="1" blah2="abc" />
    </nodeone>
    <nodeone>
        <subnode>with other stuff</subnode>
    </nodeone>
    <nodeone>
        <subnode />
    </nodeone>
</root>
```

into a file that looks like:

```
<root>
    <nodeone>
        <subnode blah="1" blah2="abc" />
    </nodeone>
    <nodeone>
        <subnode>with other stuff</subnode>
    </nodeone>
</root>
```

You can see that all of "nodeone" that had the empty children disappeared, but any `<nodeone>` with either inner content or non-blank attributes are preserved.

My current attempt at a solution is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(@*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This removes any nodes with blank inner content and preserves the attributes, but also removes the `<nodeone />` text from the output, which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a generic solution, then try this template

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(.//@*)]"/>
```

Here `.//@*` will check for attributes on the current element (being matched) and all descendant elements too.

Answer (score 0):

You're matching for elements with **any** name that have neither textual content nor attribute. So this matches your `<nodeone>` elements, too. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nodeone[*[not(normalize-space())][not(@*)]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: BTW, if you want childless `nodeone` elements (i.e. `<nodeone/>`) to also be removed, then use `<xsl:template match="nodeone[not(subnode[@*])][not(subnode[normalize-space()])]"/>` instead.

Comment: Right, so as I was saying, this is a document with arbitrary nodes in it. I don't necessarily know what they're called, but if they're empty and have no content-having attributes, I want them omitted from the output. Point being, I can't create a structure like the one you provided that selects specific nodes. Does that make sense?

Comment: So the name of `<nodeone>` is always nodeone, but `<subnode>` may have a different name? I altered my answer above to reflect this.